# PHP Newsletter technique

Tags: php, email, newsletter, bulk

I'm just a beginner of a PHP coding.
I need to know normally industry they how to trigger Newsletter to client?
is it use software/website like
https://www.phplist.com/ ?
or cronjob trigger a 'sendmail.php' and use phpmailer send bulk email ?
THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a programming question.

For newsletter, first you have to collect the emails of your target audience, then trigger email blast using loop of email function. Nothing magical.

There are some Email Blast software (if you want to use software instead of PHP) that helps you to do so, such as [SendBlaster](http://www.sendblaster.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use sendmail but the burden tends to be the rarity of whitelisted IP's these days. You'll want to use a third-party email service for sending out newsletters or you'll risk a large percentage of your emails getting bounced or junked.

There are a zillion of them. Google and decide which best fits your price point. Sendmail is mainly for one-off emails like "thanks for joining" or "here's a link to reset your password".